# how to get the count of folders if i am having the path of the file in PL/SQL?

Tags: plsql, plsqldeveloper

I want to find the count of the folders present in the specified path

For example 'C:\Users\abc'

What is the code to get the count of the files present inside this path?

Answer (score 0):

There is one way I found to do that in pure PL/SQL using `SYS.DBMS_BACKUP_RESTORE.SEARCHFILES`. It involves granting some strange rights. I have not tested it myself though. You can find more details [here](https://davidalejomarcos.wordpress.com/2011/09/13/how-to-list-files-on-a-directory-from-oracle-database/)

Basically, you create the directory, and a [pipelined function](https://www.akadia.com/services/ora_pipe_functions.html) that lists the files in the directory. Then you can simply count them.

```
create type file_array as table of varchar2(100)
/


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION COUNT_FILES (lp_string IN VARCHAR2 default null)
RETURN file_array pipelined AS

lv_pattern VARCHAR2(1024);
lv_ns VARCHAR2(1024);

BEGIN

SELECT directory_path
INTO lv_pattern
FROM dba_directories
WHERE directory_name = '<YOUR_DIR_NAME>';

SYS.DBMS_BACKUP_RESTORE.SEARCHFILES(lv_pattern, lv_ns);

FOR file_list IN (SELECT FNAME_KRBMSFT AS file_name
FROM X$KRBMSFT
WHERE FNAME_KRBMSFT LIKE '%'|| NVL(lp_string, FNAME_KRBMSFT)||'%' ) LOOP
PIPE ROW(file_list.file_name);
END LOOP;

END;
/


grant execute on LIST_FILES to public;
create public synonym list_files for sys.LIST_FILES;
```

Then you can run your query:

```
select count from table(list_files);
```

If you could not have these rights, the only way is to use external Java or C routine and call it from PL/SQL to do it for you. There is numerous [examples](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:439619916584) for Java